# how to read semicolon delimited text file in python and convert to csv

Tags: python, text, header, delimiter

I'm a complete beginner, appreciate anyone's help on this inquiry.

I have a **text file** that contains the following:

[image]

or below : (for some reason the new line is not clear here)

```
1/03/2021;6:59:59 AM.0;ServerLogic/Retain/GWSF_PPC1_LR;1.0
1/03/2021;7:00:00 AM.0;ServerLogic/Retain/GWSF_PPC1_LR;1.0
1/03/2021;6:00:01 AM.0;ServerLogic/Global/GWSF_PPC1_METF;0.0
1/03/2021;6:00:02 AM.0;ServerLogic/Global/GWSF_PPC1_METF;0.0
1/03/2021;7:29:58 AM.0;ServerLogic/Retain/GWSF_PPC1_LR;1.0
1/03/2021;7:29:59 AM.0;ServerLogic/Retain/GWSF_PPC1_LR;1.0
1/03/2021;7:30:00 AM.0;ServerLogic/Retain/GWSF_PPC1_LR;1.0
1/03/2021;7:00:01 AM.0;ServerLogic/Global/GWSF_PPC1_METF;0.0
1/03/2021;7:00:02 AM.0;ServerLogic/Global/GWSF_PPC1_METF;0.0
```

Using Google Collab, I would like to do open the file, convert the content into a table with delimiter of ";", and then add a header, so it becomes a dataframe that will look like below:

[image]

if the image above is not working, basically imagine if below is a table:

```
Date    Hour    Ignore  Parameter   Value

01-03-21    6:59:59 AM  0   ServerLogic/Retain/GWSF_PPC1_LR 1.0
01-03-21    7:00:00 AM  0   ServerLogic/Retain/GWSF_PPC1_LR 1.0
01-03-21    6:00:01 AM  0   ServerLogic/Global/GWSF_PPC1_METF   0.0
01-03-21    6:00:02 AM  0   ServerLogic/Global/GWSF_PPC1_METF   0.0
01-03-21    7:29:58 AM  0   ServerLogic/Retain/GWSF_PPC1_LR 1.0
01-03-21    7:29:59 AM  0   ServerLogic/Retain/GWSF_PPC1_LR 1.0
01-03-21    7:30:00 AM  0   ServerLogic/Retain/GWSF_PPC1_LR 1.0
01-03-21    7:00:01 AM  0   ServerLogic/Global/GWSF_PPC1_METF   0.0
01-03-21    7:00:02 AM  0   ServerLogic/Global/GWSF_PPC1_METF   0.0
```

Next, I would like to filter on the "Parameter" column with "PPC1_METF" included, so the output becomes:

[image]

```
01-03-21    6:00:01 AM  0   ServerLogic/Global/GWSF_PPC1_METF   0.0
01-03-21    6:00:02 AM  0   ServerLogic/Global/GWSF_PPC1_METF   0.0
01-03-21    7:00:01 AM  0   ServerLogic/Global/GWSF_PPC1_METF   0.0
01-03-21    7:00:02 AM  0   ServerLogic/Global/GWSF_PPC1_METF   0.0
```

Lastly, to create an output of csv file.

What I've tried is the following code:

```
    with open('gdrive_url+file_ppc','r') as in_file:
     stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
     lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
     with open('gdrive_url+file_ppc','w') as out_ppc:
       writer = csv.writer(out_ppc)
       writer.writerow(lines)
```

But I'm currently stuck at the error on the following code:

```
    with open('gdrive_url+file_ppc','r') as in_file:"
```

The error reads below:

```
    [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdrive_url+file_ppc'
```

Is it better to conver the text to csv first?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Are you expecting to use pandas, since you're talking about dataframes?

Comment: I tried the following code:with open(gdrive_url+file_ppc,'r') as in_file:
  stripped = (line.strip() for line in in_file)
  lines = (line.split(",") for line in stripped if line)
  with open('gdrive_url+file_ppc,'w') as out_ppc:
    writer = csv.writer(out_ppc)
    writer.writerow(lines)

However there's error at  with open('gdrive_url+file_ppc.csv,'w') as out_ppc:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax 'w'

Comment: Please add example code and a description of specific problems to the question, not the comments (and format the code as code, as well as the data in your question, while you're there)

Comment: You missed a quotation mark.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. I added the quotation mark to both opens, but I got another error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gdrive_url+file_ppc'

Comment: Even if I removed the quotation mark, it still gives me error, A different error: [Errno 107] Transport endpoint is not connected: 'gdrive/My Drive/Work/Signal/GWSF/DATA/P9210309041939.txt'